# How to transform html ebooks into pdf ebooks for mac osx

Tags: macos, mac, pdf, conversion, html

There is an ebook format that basically consists of a bunch of html pages, one for each book page, all in a folder, and an html page outside this folder called start_here.html . This is easy to read on a computer but really annoying on an ebook reader, or an ipad (which is my real aim).

How can I convert this bunch of html pages into a single pdf file?

I need to do it using only mac osx tools. I tried with Calibre, but it only converts about 11 pages. I don't know why. Many books have 300 pages, so doing the conversion page by page with iworks or pages is impossible.

Since it is easy to join together pdf files, an equivalent question would be: how do I transform all the html pages in a folder into pdf files?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[Set up CUPS-PDF](http://bitbucket.org/codepoet/cups-pdf-for-mac-os-x/wiki/Home), then you can use Automator's "Print Finder Items" action to print to the PDF 'printer'.

Comment: Hello, I installed CUPS-PDF. It seem to work fine when I print from Chrome. Or in general from a browser. I also set up an automator application, which works fine when I send to it a .pdf file (ok I know from pdf to pdf is trivial...). But when I send an html file to it, it does produce a pdf file, but the result file is empty. Is there any way in which I can tell him he should use a browser to open the files before printing them. By the way, this is the first time I use automator. Thanks, Pietro